# Analog Is Digital?

Tags: signal, physics

As I started reading a bit about analog vs digital signals, I keep returning to this thought. This could be something pretty obvious to the pros out there, but is it safe to assume that underneath it all, the dichotomy b/w analog and digital is a false one?

That *analog is digital, with a high enough resolution*. I am not talking about the technology involved, but the nature of the signal, itself.

To put it yet another way, *every signal is digital, we just perceive the world as analog*, which has got more to do with the bounds within which our perception/consciousness/senses (or extensions thereof) operate?! Perceptual latency. A hypothetical digital signal, with infinitesimal sampling-rate, and infinite bit-rate--although, that would somewhat defeat some purpose behind digitization--would be it's analog counterpart.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127051/discussion-on-question-by-puwlah-analog-is-digital).

Comment: [Are voltages discrete when we zoom in enough?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131674/290358) You'd be interested in looking at this question

Answer (score 5):

Digital is Analog

Digital signals are a sampled subset of analog signals and analog signals are continuous.

Every digital signal *represents* a digital high or low value (or whatever number base system is used, there are digital systems with more than two bits/voltage levels), but in physical reality all these signals are continuous. Digital signals only make sense when they are quantized and/or sampled.

Example: A digital device has an input pin, above 2.0V it detects a digital high below 0.8V it detects a digital low signal. But the actutal signal could be anywhere between the ground and supply voltage rail.

In signal theory we talk about digital signals as *sampled continuous signals*.

Comment: Yes. And \$ \text{Digital} \subset \text{Analog} \$ does not imply \$ \text{Analog} \subset \text{Digital} \$.

Answer (score 2):

everything is analog because the underlying nature of quantum physics is *analog*. digital is merely a definition of voltage thresholds and even "digital circuits" are poor at being ideally digital. they have undefined states, delays etc.

and while charge is quantized at a rather coarse level, most related quantities arent:

- voltage is continuous because capacitance is continuous.
- even current can be arbitrarily low by increasing the time between electrons. analog engineers are long aware of this (shot noise)

Answer (score 1):

- Analog and Digital are just *models* of reality, it is **not** to be confused with reality itself. It's just like how Classical and Quantum mechanics are models of the universe. We use whichever model is suitable for **solving** the problem at hand.
- It can't be said that quantum is the absolute reality or string theory is reality. They are, and will remain theories. Similarly, it can't be said that analog or digital is the absolute reality.
- The question you ask is beyond electrical engineering and even beyond Physics. It falls into Metaphysics and philosophy.
- As electrical engineers, we need to know how and when to apply the abstraction of lumped-matter circuits, digital circuits or Maxwell's equations. That's all that matters to electrical engineers. The engineer is not concerned with philosophical questions in daily work.
- There is a theory called **Digital Physics** in which our universe is digital.

Answer (score -2):

Contrary to the comments under the question I would agree, that yes, every analog signal is actually digital, only with very high resolution.

*Digital* means that things are not continuous, but quantized. And that is exactly what our world is - quantized. We do not perceive it that way in our every day, because the resolution is *really* high. But quantum mechanics taught us that there is no infinitesimally small charge. The smallest charge that can build up our electrical signals is the charge of an electron *e*. And that amount of charge is finite. And such a charge can't move by an infinitesimally distance, it has to move by at least one *planck length*.

So these basic quantaties of quantum mechanics (and quite a few other) make up the resolution of everything that happens around us. And by that it can not be real analog.

Comment: The statement that the Planck length is a minimal length of movement or a quantization of space is not true, and is likely a misunderstanding of modern physics. Planck-scale units *are* a natural scale for quantum processes, but it does not make them necessarily a quantization of position (not that such a quantization would necessarily be meaningful owing to the uncertainty principle and other considerations such as the size of an electron orbital being far larger than a Planck length anyway). Further, something being quantized doesn't make digital theory good for modeling it.

Comment: @jusaca that's what I was thinking of. Could you please point me to some research validating this hypothesis?

Comment: Except that outside of restrictive boundary conditions (which are common, but not ubiquitous), quantization either doesn't exist or is swamped by quantum uncertainty (depending on who you ask).

Comment: If signals are quanitized it is at the electron level (thats why they are called electron-ics), digitial systems do not count electrons and do not threshold by X amount of electrons, they threshold by voltage.

Comment: No, our digital signal theory might not be useful to model quantum mechanic processes. But that does not change that *digital* only means quantized. And our signals just are quantized, at least in terms of charge. I admit, I can't argue with you about wether or not planck length might be something real or not (I'm not a physicist).

Comment: Many things are not in fact discrete. There is no indication that distances between objects are discrete. That there is an underlying grid that our positions all must snap to as we move about in space. There is no indication that time is discrete. If space is not discrete, then voltage and electric fields are not discrete (because any field can be obtained by moving charges closer or farther together). Speed is not discrete. So any wavelength of light is possible (red shift and blue shift). So, it seems that you might be wrong.

Comment: You can't detect anything on that level because it is magnitudes of order smaller than the quantum level, we have a hard enough time detecting the properties of single quantum objects.

Comment: @VoltageSpike But does it make the signal continuous, only because we are not able to detect the small steps of magnitude (that might or might not be there)?

Comment: I think that in quantum things like energy level are discrete but things like Planck length (and maybe Planck time?) arise from fuzziness in measurement, which is not the same thing as thresholding and "snapping to a grid". I don't know about you, but that sounds mighty analog to me, in a quantized sort of way.

Comment: But I do see the point of @mkeith, maybe charge actually is the only quantized property we have in electronics.

Comment: Is there anywhere where a question like this can be discussed without being off-topic? Obviously it will be closed. But obviously it struck a nerve, too. What does it mean, if anything, that most analog circuits are designed and simulated on digital computers, or that the most difficult problems in digital design are actually analog problems like jitter and timing closure, etc?

Comment: @jusaca Voltages are continuous, by virtue of the electric field being continuous, just because they are measured doesn't make non-continuous.

Comment: @mkeith Isn't it just because digital is easier? Easier to deal with logically and the hardware is cheaper to implement since the flexibility lets you re-use it for many different things. I mean, the most difficult problems in digital design are analog problems. But so are the most difficult problems in analog. Because analog is difficult.

Comment: Yeah. Digital is conceptually easier. As an area of practice it becomes difficult because of the vastness of the scope compared to the scope of a project a single analog designer would be expected to tackle. @DKNguyen

Comment: @mkeith I dunno, man. To me that just sounds like the relative vastness of scope on a project for a digital designer compared to an analog designer is because digital design is easier so they can handle it. Like how playing one note at a time on a violin is okay but pretty much unacceptable on a piano.

Comment: Yeah that is what I was trying to say. I agree with you. @DKNguyen.

Comment: @DKNguyen a digital circuit designer still needs to know how to make analog circuits, and models those circuits in the analog domain to make sure they meet timing and logic level specs.

Comment: Perspective of someone/something who observes, should not change the theoretical definitions or mathematics behind it. Mathematically 'analog' is something continuous even at infinitesimal level.

Comment: @VoltageSpike who said electric field is continuous? That's true only in classical electromagnetics (Maxwell's, Volta's and Ampere's). Indeed, in modern quantum physics, energy is in discrete chunks - multiples of h (planck's constant). And of course classical electromagnetics is inadequate to explain things on the quantum scale.

Comment: @DKNguyen Look at this article: https://www.wired.com/2002/12/holytech/ Quantum might be digital underneath

Comment: @ShashankVM charge is discrete. But as far as I know, distance is continuous. Therefore field is continuous. If there are forbidden distances, please say what they are. Can two objects be separated by 1.1 meters, but 1.100000000000000000001 meters separation is not allowed? Because if the distance between two charges can be varied continuously, then field is continuous.

Comment: @mkeith yes field is continuous, but only in classical electromagnetics. In quantum electrodynamics, field is quantized. See: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-51-quantum-theory-of-radiation-interactions-fall-2012/lecture-notes/MIT22_51F12_Ch10.pdf and https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2019/04/25/this-is-why-quantum-field-theory-is-more-fundamental-than-quantum-mechanics/?sh=4e4573e2083e jusaca's answer has my upvote. It seems that the majority of EEs have only heard of classical field theory or have forgotten quantum physics.

Comment: @ShashankVM interesting. A bit beyond me nowadays but the Forbes article was very explicit that fields are also quantum. So probably I am wrong about that.